# Gitlab, is it possible to restore a clean database without reinstalling everythin

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, config, gitlab

I have recently broken my gitlab when I've decided to change mysql port to allow external connection.

After that, I was trying to restart my server with "sudo /etc/init.d mysql restart", but finally I wasn't able to restart the server, returning [FAIL] at every try.

I have readen that I could backup the files ibdata, ibadata1, ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1, 
/var/lib/mysql and help mysql to restart.

After a long time searching, I finally figure it out. to start/stop a service, the command was 
"sudo service mysql start|top".

Unfortunnatly, I lose my database i don't know how, and know all my gitlab projects are down, is there a way to restore a working database ?

Comment: Can you try a dump/restore? (as in http://serverfault.com/a/438832/783). Is it a permission issue? (as in http://community.bitnami.com/t/after-i-backup-and-restore-gitlab-mysql-could-not-be-started/20882/4)

Comment: I don't have a dump, it's a fresh install. I've tried to reinstall the rack to generate a new db but didn't work out :/